# DataBinding between two custom listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, datacontext

## What I want

I have two custom `ListBox` inside my `UserControl`.

My custom `ListBox1` has a `private List<Element> SubList` which is a sub-list of its elements. This custom control implements the `PropertyChanged` of `INotifyPropertyChanged` etc etc.

My `ListBox2` has to display this sub-list.

Both of them are also using `DataTemplate` but I do not think it will be the problem here so I will not take care of this part here. If I am wrong, let me know and I will update my example.

[image: What I want]

## What I tried

```
<UserControl>
        <local:ListBox1 x:Name="ListBox1" 
                         DataContext="{Binding MyFullList}"/>
        <local:ListBox2 x:Name="ListBox2" 
                        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1}"
                        Content="{Binding Path=SubList}"/>
</UserControl>
```

It's giving me inside my ListBox2:

(Collection)

I tried using just one element instead of the list of elements and it was working.
I also tried like this:

```
<UserControl>
            <local:ListBox1 x:Name="ListBox1" 
                             DataContext="{Binding MyFullList}"/>
            <local:ListBox2 x:Name="ListBox2" 
                            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=SubList}"/>
</UserControl>
```

But it is giving me nothing... I also tried using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` but still nothing.

## My Questions

What should be my Binding to fill `ListBox2` with the `SubList` of `ListBox1`?
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I tried using a list already filled and it was working. So the problem was during the update of the `ListBox2` and not the `DataBinding`.

I do not know why but the `List` named `SubList` was not updating the `ListBox2` even if it was triggering the `OnPropertyChanged` event, etc.

I just needed to change my `SubList` to an `ObservableCollection` and the following code is doing the `DataBinding` correctly :

```
<UserControl>
            <local:ListBox1 x:Name="ListBox1" 
                             DataContext="{Binding MyFullList}"/>
            <local:ListBox2 x:Name="ListBox2" 
                            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=SubList}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your Model class this is just a guess, but if to have a model tha contains a sublist you can bind to the ListBox1.SelectedItem and use the Sublist property

```
 <local:ListBox2 x:Name="ListBox2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=SelectedItem.SubList}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I updated my answer (the image). The SubList is a property of the ListBox1 and not of the SelectedItem. Do you have some ideas ?